# VBA find Copy and Paste by matching values in multiple column

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I need to find VBA Code. I Have 2 sheets "FinalData" and "ConsultantSheet". In "FinalData" I have a data from column A "Names" and B to R Time (1901 Rows). In "ConsultanatSheet" I have data in A1 (Names) . I want that if "FinalData" has the same name, as i have it in "ConsultantSheet" (B1) AND have values greater than 0 in  any of the cloumn (B3 TO R3) then copy Entire Row from "Final Data" and paste it in "ConsultantSheet" in A TO R. and loop from ROW 2 to ROW 1901...

Thanks in Advance for help!

```
Dim EmployeeType As String
Dim finalrow As Integer
Dim Duration As Integer
Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer

j = 2

Worksheets("Consultant Sheet").Range("A3:P2000").ClearContents
EmployeeType = Sheets("Consultant Sheet").Range("A1").Value 
finalrow = Sheets("Final Data").Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row 

For i = 2 To finalrow 

    If Worksheets("Final Data").Cells(B, 2) = EmployeeType And _
       (Worksheets("Final Data").Cells(E, 2) > 0) Or _
       (Worksheets("Final Data").Cells(F, 2) > 0) Or _
       (Worksheets("Final Data").Cells(G, 2) > 0) Or _
       (Worksheets("Final Data").Cells(H, 2) > 0) Or _
       (Worksheets("Final Data").Cells(i, 2) > 0) Or _
       (Worksheets("Final Data").Cells(j, 2) > 0) Or _
       (Worksheets("Final Data").Cells(K, 2) > 0) Or _
       (Worksheets("Final Data").Cells(L, 2) > 0) Or _
       (Worksheets("Final Data").Cells(M, 2) > 0) Or _
       (Worksheets("Final Data").Cells(N, 2) > 0) Or _
       (Worksheets("Final Data").Cells(O, 2) > 0) Or _
       (Worksheets("Final Data").Cells(P, 2) > 0) Or _
       (Worksheets("Final Data").Cells(Q, 2) > 0) Or _
       (Worksheets("Final Data").Cells(R, 2) > 0) Then        
    Worksheets("Final Data").Cells(B, 2).Resize(1, 1000).Copy
    Worksheets("Final Data").Cells(j, "P").Resize(1, 1000).PasteSpecial xlPasteNumberFormats 
        j = j + 1
    End If 
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: What have you tried, and what problems did you run into?  This is not really a place for "finding" code - you are expected to post your efforts and describe what's not working.

Comment: This is what i am using

Comment: So what's the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Untested:

```
Dim EmployeeType As String
Dim finalrow As Integer
Dim Duration As Integer
Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer
Dim shtCS As Worksheet, shtFD As Worksheet, rw As Range

Set shtCS = Worksheets("Consultant Sheet")
Set shtFD = Worksheets("Final Data")

j = 2

shtCS.Range("A3:P2000").ClearContents
EmployeeType = shtCS.Range("A1").Value
finalrow = shtFD.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 2 To finalrow

    Set rw = shtFD.Rows(i)

    If rw.Cells(, "B") = EmployeeType And _
        Application.CountIf(rw.Cells(, "E").Resize(1, 14), ">0") > 0 Then

        'EDITED: copy values only
        shtCS.Cells(j, 1).Resize(1, 50).value = rw.Cells(1).Resize(1, 50).Value
        j = j + 1

    End If
Next i
```

Comment: Thanks and it's copy the formula. I need just to paste NUMBERS not formula.